# If i have changed the configs file in Iguana Tinker Tweaks can my friends still join my lan game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-tinkers-construct

I have changed the configs in Iguana Tweaks. If i'm hosting a LAN world will my friends then also have to change his configs or is the game using mine?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, configs should match. If they don't, they will be able to connect, but they will experience bugs (such as inability to craft) and possibly crashes.